# Application crashes when writing MJPEG file. Is there a way to stop this or CATCH it and prevent a crash?

Tags: android, exception, camera, mjpeg

I am developing an application for remote field use that will collect and store video data in MJPEG format. I am currently developing for the IP67 rated Samsung i9295 S4 phone. The location where this will be deployed has no cellular network coverage. The application runs as expected except that every 3-6 days, the application crashes. I "suspect" that the problem may be in the below code block, however I am not getting the expected appendLog() error messages from CATCH.

**Two questions:** Is there anything obviously missing from the code below that I should implement that would keep resources freed up and prevent memory leaks? Is there a better way to catch this issue that will prevent the application crashes that I am currently having?

Thanks in advance...

```
@Override
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] b, Camera c) {
    if (bRecordingFlag ) {
        if (parameters.getPreviewFormat() == ImageFormat.NV21) {
            Log.v(LOGTAG,"Started Writing Frame");
            try {
                byte[] jpegByteArray;
                makeNewTimestamps();
                YuvImage im = new YuvImage(b, ImageFormat.NV21, parameters.getPreviewSize().width, parameters.getPreviewSize().height, null);
                Rect r = new Rect(0,0,parameters.getPreviewSize().width,parameters.getPreviewSize().height);
                ByteArrayOutputStream jpegByteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                im.compressToJpeg(r, iJpegQuality, jpegByteArrayOutputStream);
                jpegByteArray = jpegByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
                byte[] boundaryBytes = (szBoundaryStart + jpegByteArray.length + " bytes" + szAbsoluteTime + szDateTime + szJpegQuality + iJpegQuality + "%" + szFramesPerSecond + iFps +szCamcorderFrame + camcorderProfile.videoFrameHeight +" x "+ camcorderProfile.videoFrameWidth + szCamcorderBitrate + camcorderProfile.videoBitRate + szLightLevel + fLightLevel + szBoundaryEnd).getBytes();
                bos.write(boundaryBytes);       
                jpegByteArray = jpegByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
                bos.write(jpegByteArray);       
                bos.flush();
                fos.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                String szStackTrace = Log.getStackTraceString(e);
                appendLog(" - Exception at onPreviewFrame()." + szStackTrace);
            }
            Log.v(LOGTAG,"Finished Writing Frame");
        } else {
            Log.v(LOGTAG,"NOT THE RIGHT FORMAT");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wild guess, but catching `OutOfMemoryError` is always a good idea when working with images.

Comment: Good suggestion. But after implementation this still did not catch my app crash.

Comment: This is a massively frustrating problem. The application runs great for 100-150 hours, then the program crashes. No error messages, nothing in log files...just back to the Android desktop. I am wondering if this could be hardware related rather than software or IO?